# Why can't the properties of anonymous types be swapped within arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, anonymous-types

I know that in C# I can declare an array of anonymous types like this:

```
var anons = new[]
{
    new { name = "" , something = ""},
    new { name = "", something = "" }
};
```

I can understand that all the objects need to have the same properties, or else one won't be able to iterate through them and use those properties like:

```
foreach (var anon in anons)
{
    Console.WriteLine(anon.name);
}
```

But what I don't understand is **why do their properties need to have the same order?**

For example, the following code won't compile:

```
var anons = new[]
{
    new { name = "" , something = ""},
    new { something = "", name = "" }
};
```

Why isn't this allowed, since in a *normal* object, the properties can be declared no matter their order, and the rest of the code could use them, as it does right now?

Comment: It's probably to simplify the compiler and hashcode generation, and to prevent differences in `ToString()` output, but I'm not sure any of us can explain *why* a particular design decision was made.

Comment: @Amy this is indeed more of a question about compiler design rather than a question about how to do something, and in this case there are indeed a few people who can answer it entirely. I am just hoping to get the closest answer to reality.

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation for anonymous types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

> If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a *sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the same names and types*, the compiler treats the objects as instances of the same type. They share the same compiler-generated type information.

In other words, you're creating two anonymous types and the sequence of property names and property types don't match. They look pretty much the same to us, but the compiler sees them as two different types, which means that it can't infer one type for the array declaration.

Comment: That's correct. I'd also recommend adding [this link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlACxwCyAFAJQlkXsBuAhgE5xcA7APYDEcALxwBAUwDuJKVwC20iXABE6gDRwAzkJUAXABYBLAQHM1muAF806dp179hA/JJnzieg9JPmVpKaOgLKqsHqdg7sthi2QA===) to the answer to help clarify the difference in compilation between the two anonymous types.

Comment: In this case I'm not sure it helps. We already know that the compiler is generating two types, one for each sequence of properties. Seeing the compiler-generated code is interesting, but it just confirms what we know.

Comment: I can see that the compiler does not allow declaring two different anonymous objects with swapped properties into an array, but why is that? I mean was it to costly to implement and just not worth, or is it something else?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a scenario to consider: What if instead of two properties there were many more - let's say twenty - and two declarations have them in entirely different sequences. Technically the compiler could sort that out and figure that they were the same type, but it would be really confusing to look at. If you thought they were the same but the compiler said they weren't, how would you figure it out? You'd have to sort all of the properties to figure out where the differences are.

Comment: Indeed, I believe that they had no reason to allow having the properties in different order, so this is why the compiler gives this error now. And @ScottHannen please tag people with the @ symbol so they get notified when you reply to them :)

Answer (score -1):

Even though the answer given by Scott is virtually correct, it does not answer the *why* question entirely. Since this is a question more about the compiler design regarding anonymous types array, and most of us can't come up with a clear answer, I will keep the question open and postpone accepting an answer until somebody answers the *why* question. Meanwhile I will leave here the following theory:

To the question

> why do their properties need to have the same order?

Why not?

Since one can declare an array of anonymous types right now, having the possibility to swap the order of the properties within objects would not help anybody.

Contrarily to this, changing the order of the properties of an anonymous object within the objects of an array of anonymous types can be misleading and for the sake of consistency should be avoided. In this case, a warning or a at least a message should be displayed for the programmers who are trying to swap the properties of the objects like that so why not making it an error from the beginning and remove the need to make the C# compiler smart enough to sort out the properties itself.

**In conclusion:** Having the properties always in the same order is not a missing functionality, but a feature.